# converting hssf worbook to xssf workbook not giving desired results

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I have a java application which is used for converting hssf workbook to xssf wokbook.There are predefined templates for the workbook.let the workbook be E.I want to onvert it from E.xls to E.xlsx.I am able to do the conversion and the data is also getting populated.I just want certain sheets in E.xls workbbok to get converted to E.xlsx workbook.The problem am facing is that in the resultant E.xlsx format am getting an extra sheet generated which is not required and also it is not populated:

```
     public String convertXlsToXlsx(String sourceXlsFile,String destinationXlsxFile) {
       log.info("Convertion from xls to xlsx Started...");

    inpFn = sourceXlsFile;
    // String xlsxIn = "D:\\arusha\\230029_06-30-2009_A.xlsx";
    outFn = destinationXlsxFile;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inpFn));

        Workbook wbIn = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
        File outF = new File(outFn);

        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(
                new File(outFn));
        XSSFWorkbook outFn_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);

        int sheetCnt = wbIn.getNumberOfSheets();
        System.out.println("The number of sheeetsss is"+sheetCnt);
        for (int i = 0; i < sheetCnt; i++) {

            Sheet sIn = wbIn.getSheetAt(i);
            XSSFSheet outFnSheet = outFn_workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        if (wbIn.isSheetHidden(i)) {
                outFn_workbook.setSheetHidden(i, true);
                continue;
            }
            if (wbIn.isSheetVeryHidden(i)) {
                outFn_workbook.setSheetHidden(i, true);
                continue;
            }

            Iterator<Row> rowIt = sIn.rowIterator();
            while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
                Row rowIn = rowIt.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIt = rowIn.cellIterator();
                while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cellIn = cellIt.next();

                    if (outFnSheet.getRow(cellIn.getRowIndex()) == null) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Cell cellOut = outFnSheet.getRow(cellIn.getRowIndex())
                            .getCell(cellIn.getColumnIndex());

                    if (cellOut == null) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ((cellOut + "").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("X")
                            && !(cellIn + "").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                        XSSFCellStyle cs = outFn_workbook.createCellStyle();
                        XSSFFont font = outFn_workbook.createFont();
                        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 6);
                        cs.setFont(font);
                        cellOut.setCellStyle(cs);
                        XSSFCellStyle cellstyle = outFn_workbook
                                .createCellStyle();
                        cellstyle.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        cellOut.setCellStyle(cellstyle);
                    }
                    switch (cellIn.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getErrorCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        cellOut.setCellFormula(cellIn.getCellFormula());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        try {

            // important to close InputStream
            input_document.close();
            // Open FileOutputStream to write updates
            FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    outFn));
            // write changes

            outFn_workbook.write(output_file);

            System.out.println("sheet removed");

            // close the stream
            output_file.close();

            // wbOut.write(out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("XlsToXlsx:",e);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("XlsToXlsx:",e);
        }
    }
    return outFn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I tried removing the sheet using removeSheetAt() method but it is not giving me the desired results.Kindly help me.Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Nothing in your code creates a new sheet in `XSSFWorkbook outFn_workbook` so all sheets in the resultant `*.xlsx` must had been already in the file on path `destinationXlsxFile` before.

Comment: Yes...the sheet is already present but I don't want that sheet in the resultant workbook.For example:If I want to convert E.xls to E.xlsx.Both have same predefined templates.In E.xls it has E1,E2,E3 etc.Now that  when I want to convert to E.xlsx I require only E1,E2 and dont want E3.The problem is E3 is also getting included.

Comment: Then you need removing the unwanted sheets from the `XSSFWorkbook outFn_workbook` before writing it out.

Comment: Yeaa...Itried doing it with removesheetAt() method but no use.

Comment: But your code iterates over all sheets in `Workbook wbIn`. So all those sheets will be processed. So where is the criteria which of those sheets shall not be processed? What determinates which sheets needs to be removed from `XSSFWorkbook outFn_workbook`?